# Safely overwrite remote branch (origin)

Tags: git, github, git-push

I have a local branch that has diverged from its remote counterpart. I want to keep the local changes and just drop the remote branch, I don't need the remote anymore. I am wondering how safe it is to "overwrite" the remote branch by simply using

```
git push -f
```

Is that safe? Will it just delete the remote branch and create a new one given my local branch?

Is there a better way to do this? I need to do this in an automated fashion (with a shell script), so I can't really manually go to Github, delete the branch and then push.

To be specific, the reason the local branch has diverged from the remote is because I have called

```
git reset --soft <another-branch>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not going to "delete" the remote branch. However, the remote branch will now point to your diverged local HEAD. Force pushing is fine as long as you're confident it's what you want to do. The only thing worth mentioning is that you'll orphan some commits from your old remote HEAD which will eventually get GC'd.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense, do you think the git history will remain clean?

Comment: I added one detail to the original question, explaining why the local branch has diverged from the remote branch.

Answer (score 1):

Your question (and follow-up in some comments) suggests some confusion about what branches *are* in git.  Other source control systems might have you trained to think that a branch is a series of deltas; in git that's a totally different thing.

A branch is just a pointer to a commit.  The branch itself knows nothing of change history; git finds that information by starting at the commit pointed to by the branch (which contains the most recent changes) and working back through "parent commit" pointers to find additional commits (which hold earlier changes).

The branch and the line of commits are totally separate things.  Updating the branch (e.g. pushing), overwriting it (forcing it to point to a different commit), or even deleting it... none of these have any effect on the series of commits.  And it's the series of commits that ensures the integrity of your history.

So is it "safe"?  Yes.  Will the history still be clean?  Yes, though the commits that *used to be* on the remote branch may no longer be reachable (meaning they could eventually be deleted by `gc`).

The only thing to watch out for is if other users have clones of the same remote repo.  They will need a recovery procedure very similar to that explained in the `git rebase` documentation ("recovering from an upstream rebase" or some such).

Comment: Hmmm that last bit concerns me - I am the only one working on this branch, so I am hoping that it won't affect anyone else.

Comment: I added one detail to the original question, explaining why the local branch has diverged from the remote branch.